# Set a picture as a background for the page

Tags: html, css

It is such that I must have a "Free" out next to my box so content as I show in this photograph.

[image]

It is such that I must have a picture here, but it will not appear on the page. I've tried swapping the absolute and relative but it does not work quite the way I want,

**CSS**

```
.opretbrugerBimg {
    position: absolute;
}
.opretimg {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: -15px;
    background-image:url('/img/gratis/gratis-logo.png');
}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="opretbrugerBimg">
<div class="opretimg">
</div>
         <div class="post">
              <!---- Here are the contents of the page --->
         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you tried adding z-index with absolute position???

Comment: Are you sure of the image path ? Because adding a `/` on the left, means path starting from the root directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.opretimg {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: -15px;
    background-image:url('/img/gratis/gratis-logo.png');
    /** maybe that's all you need haha**/
    width:###px;
    height:###px;

}
```

**width** and **height**

Comment: oohhh Yea, its work now, men but now repeat images several times,

Comment: background-repeat:no-repeat; I think

Answer (score 0):

use this css.

```
.opretbrugerBimg {
    position: relative;
}
.opretimg {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: -15px;
    background-image:url('/img/gratis/gratis-logo.png');
width: 100px;  // change this width and height as per the image.  
height:100px;
z-index:2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into your html code and look for your body tag and put it like this..

```
<body style="background-image:url('/img/gratis/gratis-logo.png')">
.
.
.
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

try `background-image:url('../img/gratis/gratis-logo.png');`

Comment: i did not got your point - why you have added .. in the path here?